# Determine the center of mass of a triangular lamina shown whose density at any point is equal to its distance from the x-axis.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Determine the center of mass of a triangular lamina shown whose density at any point is equal to its distance from the x-axis.
The triangle has vertices at (0,0)(3,9)(7,0).

Comment: Where's the "triangular lamina shown"?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to post the picture. The lamina is the line from point (0,0) to (3,9)

Comment: What's the link? Tell me and I'll edit the question.

Comment: There are standard formulas, calculate the mass and the moments about the axes.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by one-variable methods, but because of the tag we use two variables. Let $T$ be our triangle. Then the mass $m$ is given by
$$m=\iint_T y \,dx\,dy.$$
The moment $A$ about the $y$-axis is given by
$$\iint_T xy \,dx\,dy.$$
The moment $B$ about the $x$-axis is given by
$$\iint_T y^2 \,dx\,dy.$$
The centre of mass is $\left(\frac{A}{m},\frac{B}{m}\right)$.

There are $3$ double integrals to evaluate.